# How to call constructor of the generic class explicitly in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, generics, selenium-webdriver, constructor

I have the below class, how can I invoke the constructor of the class explicitly?

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
    public class BaseWebDriver<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
    {
        public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
        public WebDriverWait wait;

        public BaseWebDriver()
        {
            Driver = new TWebDriver();
        }

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public virtual void SetupTest()
        {
            // Go to the login page
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("LoginUrl");
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public virtual void TearDownTest()
        {
            Driver.Quit();
            Driver.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("***TearDown***\n");
        }

public void restartBrowser()
{
Driver.Quit();
//Here I have to call the constructor of the class to open the browser again 
}

     }
```

Is it possible to call the constructor from a derived class? I am new to generics, so kindly help.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You *are* calling the constructor when call `new blah()`. If you need that functionality outside the constructor, then move it into a public method of it's own.

Comment: Why not just use `Driver = new TWebDriver();` again? If you want, you can refactor it to a separate function and call that from both the constructor and `restartBrowser`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Driver = new TWebDriver() works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew said, Driver = new TWebDriver() works. Thanks.